# Why are there multiple calls to my function when it has been called only once during iteration?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application which uses Xerces for Iteration. I have a custom method which is called to store a filtered set of data values in it after being iterated through via a while loop. Part of the specific while loop is as follows:

```
while((n = iterator.nextNode())!= null) {
    ... //other code

    object.customMethod(tagName, n.getNodeValue()); //occurs only once per iteration
    Log.i("TAG", tagName + ": " + n.getNodeValue())

    ...//other code
}
```

The `customMethod` received a key and value pair and saves them as Strings using Android's SharedPreferences system. At the moment of being called, the method actually has the key=>value pair, but it appears the method is being called more than once during the same iteration loop. I came to know this after printing out the logcat sample showing the output after each call within customMethod due to having blanks/nulls saved in the preferences when I fetched them later. Why is this happening? A sample output is as shown:

> TAG inserted: 500.00 //log call right after insertion within customMethod()
>
> TAG vc:limit: 500.00 //log call after returning from customMethod()
>
> TAG inserted:
>
> TAG inserted:
>
> TAG inserted: //other calls, which I want to know how and why they are occurring

All the above occurred during a single iteration of the while loop. Anyone know why this is happening? Something else, it seems the code right after the insertion only runs once, but only the code within the `customMethod()` gets called several times during the iteration. The custom method is as shown below:

```
public boolean customMethod(String key, String val) {
    boolean inserted = prefs.edit().putString(key, val).commit(); //prefs is global
    Log.i("TAG", (inserted == true ? "inserted: " + val : "not inserted"));
    return inserted;
}
```

Edit: The full while loop as requested:

```
private void setSelectedID(int pos)
{
    ...
    String id = IDs[pos];
    ...

    NodeList descElements = MainActivity.root.getElementsByTagName(VCard.DIRECTORY); //DIRECTORY is a String constant
    Element desc = (Element) descElements.item(0);
    NodeIterator iterator = ((DocumentTraversal)MainActivity.doc).createNodeIterator(desc, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, null, true);

    Node n;
    VCard object = new VCard(this);

    while((n = iterator.nextNode())!= null)
    {
        if(n.getNodeType() == Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE || n.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
        {
            String tagName = n.getParentNode().getNodeName();
            if(object.containsKey(tagName))
            {
                Element e = (Element) n.getParentNode();
                if(e.hasAttribute("id") && e.getAttribute("id").equals(id))
                {
                    object.customMethod(tagName, n.getNodeValue());
                    Log.i("TAG", tagName + ": " + n.getNodeValue())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "All the above occurred during a single iteration of the while loop." Are you sure?  How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: How are you defining the iterator? Have you tried iterator.next() instead of nextnode() ? Or just check if iterator.hasNext() in the while condition block, and iterate within the while loop.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede See the Log call right after the `customMethod` insertion and also within the `customMethod()`? That helped me track the number of iterations during the parsing. They match the number of elements expected from the parsing. But the Log calls from within the customMethod() far exceed the expected number of calls during the iteration, as seen above from a single iteration.

Comment: @HPP my definition: `NodeIterator iterator = ((DocumentTraversal)MainActivity.doc).createNodeIterator(desc, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, null, true);`

Comment: @HPP I have not yet tried `next()` Update: NodeIterator has no next() function

Comment: You are probably not running the same code that you are looking at, make sure to clean and rebuild. Also, you should check for interceptor if you have that kind of things in your application.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope I have no idea what Interceptors are, thus am quite sure I haven't used them anywhere in my code

Comment: Aren't customMethod your object and setTagData(...) your method ?

Comment: Show what you've commented as "other code".